# How to change the text of a single button in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am having a List of Jobs with Approve button.

### Expected Result

Whenever the **Approve** button next to a Job is clicked, the Job should be approved and the button text should say **Approved**.

### Original Outcome

The text of all the buttons gets changed to **Approved**, but only a single Job gets approved, i.e. the job the was actually approved. Also the text stays approved for all the jobs until the page is refreshed.

```
export default class ProfilePage extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      allJobs: [],
      loading: true,
      newLoading: false,
      valueApprove: "Approve",
      _id: ""
    };

    this.handleApproveJob = this.handleApproveJob.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    var apiUrl = `http://localhost:5000/admin/pendingJobs`;
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        let allJobsFromApi = data.PendingJobs.map(job => {
          return {
            jobmainid: job._id,
            companyName: job.companyNane,
            contactPerson: job.contactPerson,
            jobTitle: job.jobTitle,
            jobDescription: job.description,
            jobCategory: job.category.name,
            jobDuration: job.duration,
            descriptionLink: job.descriptionLink,
            status: job.status
          }
        })
        this.setState({ allJobs: allJobsFromApi, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  handleApproveJob(e) {
    this.setState({
      newLoading: true
    })
    e.preventDefault();
    var jobId = e.target.getAttribute('jobId');
    console.log(jobId);
    const job = {
      approvedJobId: jobId
    };
    approveJob(job).then((res, err) => {
      if (res) {
        this.setState({
          newLoading: false,
          valueApprove: "Approved"
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          message: "some error occured"
        })
      }
    })
  }

render() {
    const { newLoading, valueApprove } = this.state;
    return (
            <div className="tile-body">
              {loading ? <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-4"><img src= 
                 {LoadingSpinner} /></div> : <table
                   className="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive"
                    id="sampleTable"
                    style={{ border: "none" }}
                    >
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Company Name</th>
                          <th>Contact Person At Company</th>
                          <th>Job Title</th>
                          <th>Job Description</th>
                          <th>Job Description Link</th>
                          <th>Category</th>
                          <th>Duration</th>                          
                          <th>Edit</th>
                          <th>Approve</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {this.state.allJobs.map((job) =>
                          <tr key={job.jobmainid}>
                            <td>{job.companyName}</td>
                            <td>{job.contactPerson}</td>
                            <td>{job.jobTitle}</td>
                            <td>{job.jobDescription}</td>                            
                            <td>
                              <a href={job.descriptionLink} target="_blank">{job.descriptionLink}</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{job.jobCategory}</td>
                            <td>{job.jobDuration}</td>
                            <td>
                              <Link to={"/admin/editJob/" + job.jobmainid}>
                                <button className="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                              </Link>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <button
                                type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-success"
                                jobId={job.jobmainid}
                                onClick={this.handleApproveJob}
                              >
                                { newLoading ? <ButtonLoading /> : valueApprove }
                          </button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                        )}

                      </tbody>
                    </table>}
                  </div>


The code for aproveJob() function
//Approve Job
export const approveJob = job => {
    return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/admin/approveJob", {
        _id: job.approvedJobId
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: try adding `this.state.newLoading` and `this.state.valueApprove`.

Comment: Can you please share how are you rendering the list of jobs with approve buttons?

Comment: I have edited and shared the necessary code. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are only storing a single variable with the approved state. Instead we need one per button.

You could do something like the below code.

1. After getting the array jobs from the server inject a value `approved: false`
2. On button click find and update that item in your state with `approved: true`

I'm not certain the code below runs but it will point you in the right direction.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export const approveJob = (job) => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:5000/admin/approveJob', {
    _id: job.approvedJobId
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

export default class ProfilePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      allJobs: [],
      loading: true,
      newLoading: false
    }

    this.handleApproveJob = this.handleApproveJob.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:5000/admin/pendingJobs`
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const allJobsFromApi = data.PendingJobs.map((job) => {
          return {
            jobmainid: job._id,
            companyName: job.companyNane,
            contactPerson: job.contactPerson,
            jobTitle: job.jobTitle,
            jobDescription: job.description,
            jobCategory: job.category.name,
            jobDuration: job.duration,
            descriptionLink: job.descriptionLink,
            status: job.status,
            approved: false
          }
        })
        this.setState({ allJobs: allJobsFromApi, loading: false })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  handleApproveJob(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault()

    this.setState({
      newLoading: true
    })
    const jobId = e.target.getAttribute('jobId')
    console.log(jobId)
    const job = {
      approvedJobId: jobId
    }
    approveJob(job).then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        const newAllJobs = this.state.allJobs
        newAllJobs[index].approved = true
        this.setState({
          newLoading: false,
          valueApprove: 'Approved',
          allJobs: newAllJobs
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          message: 'some error occured'
        })
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, newLoading, valueApprove, allJobs } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="tile-body">
        {loading ? (
          <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <img src={LoadingSpinner} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <table
            className="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive"
            id="sampleTable"
            style={{ border: 'none' }}
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Contact Person At Company</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Job Description</th>
                <th>Job Description Link</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Approve</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {allJobs.map((job, index) => (
                <tr key={job.jobmainid}>
                  <td>{job.companyName}</td>
                  <td>{job.contactPerson}</td>
                  <td>{job.jobTitle}</td>
                  <td>{job.jobDescription}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href={job.descriptionLink} target="_blank">
                      {job.descriptionLink}
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>{job.jobCategory}</td>
                  <td>{job.jobDuration}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Link to={'/admin/editJob/' + job.jobmainid}>
                      <button className="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                    </Link>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success"
                      jobId={job.jobmainid}
                      onClick={(e) => this.handleApproveJob(e, index)}
                    >
                      {newLoading ? <ButtonLoading /> : valueApprove}
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, that was my bad as I forgot to mention that I have already destructured both newLoading and valueApprove.
 const { newLoading, valueApprove } = this.state;

Comment: @Dev can you include the rest of the code including the approveJob() function?

Comment: sure. Here is my code for approveJob() function :

//Approve Job
export const approveJob = job => {
    return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/admin/approveJob", {
        _id: job.approvedJobId
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

Comment: can you rather edit your question to include the entire class. Piecing it together like this means we might miss something

Comment: I have edited the question and put up the necessary code.

Comment: @Dev my answer updated with a more complete solution

Comment: thanks for your updated answer. It did point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
handleApproveJob(e) {
    this.setState({
      newLoading: true
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    var jobId = e.target.getAttribute('jobId');
    console.log(jobId);
    const job = {
      approvedJobId: jobId
    };

    let self = this;

    approveJob(job).then((res, err) => {
      if (res) {
        self.setState({
          newLoading: false,
          valueApprove: "Approved"
        })
      } else {
        self.setState({
          loading: false,
          message: "some error occured"
        })
      }
    })
  }


<button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" jobId={job.jobmainid} onClick={this.handleApproveJob}> 
   { this.state.newLoading ? <ButtonLoading /> : this.state.valueApprove }
</button>
```

I hope I've been there for you. Let me know.

Comment: thanks for looking into the issue. But I am still getting all the buttons with text as Approved

Answer (score 0):

Three things are there.

1. you need to add `approve: false` to every item in the jobs
2. On clicking approve button of any job, you need to pass index of that job in the `approveJob(index)` function.
3. Depending on the index value (which was passed in `approveJob(index)`) you need to updated the particular job in the job array in the state.

Just update the render function code for approve button, as you need change text on clicking button

```
  render() {
    const { loading, newLoading, valueApprove, allJobs } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="tile-body">
        {loading ? (
          <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <img src={LoadingSpinner} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <table
            className="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive"
            id="sampleTable"
            style={{ border: 'none' }}
          >
            <tbody>
              {allJobs.map((job, index) => (
                <tr key={job.jobmainid}>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success"
                      jobId={job.jobmainid}
                      onClick={(e) => this.handleApproveJob(e, index)}
                    >
                      {job.approved ? "approved" : "approve"}
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```